# How can I resolve the error "Purchase error" in the Windows 8 app store?

Tags: windows-8-preview

I installed Windows 8 Release Priview over Windows 7.
I use Lan and Wifi
Though I can access the browser and the apps, I cannot install any app from the App Store.
It says Purchase Error.
Please help.